# JSON received but error for "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json"

Tags: jquery, html, json

Im parseing a **JSON**  file and add the data to a `HTML` dropdown , code as follows,

```
$.getJSON(
    "http://mobile.icta.lk/services/railwayservice/getAllLines.php?lang=en&jsoncallback=?",
    function(data) {

        var $s = $('.txtline').empty();

        // the actual contents of this loop will be
        // specific to the data
        for (var k in data) {
            $('<option></option>')
                .val(data[k].value)
                .text(data[k].text)
                .appendTo($s);
        }
    }
)
```

Im getting a error as,

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json.

getAllLines.php:2Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Comment: Does the content returned from server begin with `{` or `jQueryLOTSOFNUMBERS({`?

Comment: @SalmanA look it up yourself (not to sound too smarmy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little script:

```
<?php
    // file url: http://localhost/remote-json-proxy.php
    $url = 'http://mobile.icta.lk/services/railwayservice/getAllLines.php';
    $qsa = '?';
    foreach($_GET as $n => $v) {
        if($n != 'callback') {
            $qsa .= '&' . $n . '=' . rawurlencode($v);
        }
    }
    $json = file_get_contents($url . $qsa);
    echo sprintf('%s(%s);', $_GET['callback'], $json);
?>
```

Usage:

```
<!-- file url: http://localhost/test.htm -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $.getJSON('remote-json-proxy.php?lang=en&this=that&callback=?', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: thanks salman ill implement this code and accept the asnwer .. i have one prob can i keep `remote-json-proxy.php` in a remote server than the `test.htm` ?

Comment: I think it will still work if you put it onto another server since the script returns JSONP.

Comment: excellent it works it returns a `object` now should find the way to populate it to a dropdown

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that this remote server returns JSON, not JSONP. It returns:

```
{"lines":[{"line":"COLOMBO - BADULLA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MATALE"},{"line":"COLOMBO - PUTTLAM"},{"line":"COLOMBO - THANDIKULAM"},{"line":"COLOMBO - TALAIMANNAR"},{"line":"COLOMBO - BATTICALOA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - TRINCOMALEE"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MATARA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - AVISSAWELLA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MIHINTALE"}]}
```

instead of:

```
someCallbackName({"lines":[{"line":"COLOMBO - BADULLA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MATALE"},{"line":"COLOMBO - PUTTLAM"},{"line":"COLOMBO - THANDIKULAM"},{"line":"COLOMBO - TALAIMANNAR"},{"line":"COLOMBO - BATTICALOA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - TRINCOMALEE"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MATARA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - AVISSAWELLA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MIHINTALE"}]})
```

You will not be able to consume a remote domain using AJAX unless this remote resource supports JSONP.

Comment: but he's not actually receiving jsonp nor asking for it, is he?

Comment: @jcolebrand, I think he is asking for it. Otherwise why would he have used an absolute path when defining his url? That's a cross domain AJAX issue IMHO.

Comment: I noticed that, as well the fact that it calls a jsoncallback with a ? param, but it could just be a matter of forcing it to call the right thing. But fwiw, that was the first thing I noticed on the Q myself.

Comment: so how i can fetch data from this server in a any method ?

Comment: @Sudantha, two possibilities: either this server supports JSONP as shown in my answer in which case you can use jQuery to consume it directly or if not you will need to write a server side bridge script on your domain which calls the remote domain and then have jQuery send a simple AJAX request to your server side script instead of the remote domain: `$.getJSON('/myscript', function(data) { ... });`

Comment: @sudanta: You can write an AJAX proxy script with less than 10 lines of PHP code. Will that be acceptable?

Comment: @sudanta: try searching for *json proxy php script*. I've also posted an answer... a very primitive PHP script that might do the job.