# JQuery AJAX response with 200, but no response data, for some remote URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jquery, cross-domain

There are several questions on Stack Overflow saying cross domain AJAX request etc will not work because of security reasons. Some questions like [this explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840825/ajax-with-jquery-200-ok-but-not-success) this. (Please let me know if I am wrong.)

This is working perfectly fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=test&callback=?", function(data) {
    alert("test alert outside loop");
    $.each(data.results, function() {
      alert("test alert inside loop");
    });
  });
});
```

But just replacing the URL with my application won't work. In that case response code is `200`, but there's no response data. There is an hit on my application; I can see that in console.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.2:3000/cities.json?callback=?", function(data) {
    alert("test alert outside loop");
    $.each(data.results, function() {
      alert("test alert inside loop");
    });
  });
});
```

I am developing a very simple mobile app using PhoneGap so I need to make this call using JavaScript. But the main thing that's confusing me is why the Twitter call is working, but the call to my app isn't. I've also tried to remove the `protect_from_forgery` call in my application controller in my Rails app, but i don't think that matters.

**EDIT**

i have deployed the app on http://deals.textadda.com/cities.json now check it... Its not working..

U can try it. these two links http://jsfiddle.net/2arbY/
http://jsfiddle.net/fHxf9/

Comment: Where are you calling these functions from? A server, or your local machine? Is `http://192.168.1.2` the IP address of the machine running the script?

Comment: @Alex i have deployed the app on http://deals.textadda.com/cities.json now check it... Its not working..

Comment: [This seems related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591987/json-received-but-error-for-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with/6592013#6592013). Looks like you're returning JSON from the server, not JSONP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this remote server returns JSON, not JSONP. It returns:

```
{"lines":[{"line":"COLOMBO - BADULLA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MATALE"},{"line":"COLOMBO - PUTTLAM"},{"line":"COLOMBO - THANDIKULAM"},{"line":"COLOMBO - TALAIMANNAR"},{"line":"COLOMBO - BATTICALOA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - TRINCOMALEE"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MATARA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - AVISSAWELLA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MIHINTALE"}]}
```

instead of:

```
someCallbackName({"lines":[{"line":"COLOMBO - BADULLA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MATALE"},{"line":"COLOMBO - PUTTLAM"},{"line":"COLOMBO - THANDIKULAM"},{"line":"COLOMBO - TALAIMANNAR"},{"line":"COLOMBO - BATTICALOA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - TRINCOMALEE"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MATARA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - AVISSAWELLA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MIHINTALE"}]})
```

Thats why I was not be able to consume a remote domain using AJAX unless this remote resource supports JSONP.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `data.results` doesn't exist, even if `data` does.  What do you get if you `alert(data);` (or `console.log(data);` ) outside the loop?

EDIT

Your app isn't generating a callback wrapper.  For instance, http://deals.textadda.com/cities.json?callback=abc should generate a JSON object wrapped in a function call of `abc`, in the same way, for example, the twitter response does: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=test&callback=abc.

Comment: Ah.  What happens, than, if you put the bare url(ie http://192.168.1.2/cities.json) into a browser.  what's the response?

Comment: take a look on this.. it returns a json response http://cl.ly/2W123L1j3G1x0e1n2R1x

Comment: @grapphicdivine i have deployed the app on http://deals.textadda.com/cities.json now check it... Its not working..

Comment: I am not getting you. Can you explain what should i do.. L

Comment: Well, if the JSON response isn't generating a callback, possibly just a call to `cities.json` (without the `?callback=?` modifier) is enough.

Comment: Dude... even thats not workin.... U can try it. these two links http://jsfiddle.net/2arbY/ http://jsfiddle.net/fHxf9/

Comment: Well, accessing the json from jsfiddle isn't going to work because of same-origin-policy.  If you need to access from the JSON from a different domain to where it is served from, then you need to fix the callback wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

you are running into cross-domain issues due to `same-origin-policy` the ip you are trying to get the json from should reside on the same sever from which you are originating the request.

try using

```
 $.getJSON("192.168.1.2/cities.json?callback=?", func
```

Comment: i have deployed the app on http://deals.textadda.com/cities.json now check it... Its not working..

Comment: the json is received... the success handler does not get called?

Comment: then whats the solution.. I m using phonegap so i need to do this in javascript...